# ошибка: Участник имеет защищенную видимость. phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Господа разработчики будьте добры подскажите пожалуйста. Код работает, но phpstorm выдает ошибку: Участник имеет защищенную видимость. Грешу на настройки phpstorm.

```
class Grandfather {
    private $borch = "деда рецепт борща";    
    protected function getBorch() { 
        return $this->borch;
    }
}


class Father extends Grandfather { 
    public function getBorch() {
        $borch = parent::getBorch(); /////////getBorch() ошибка 
        $borch .= " очень вкусный"; 
        echo $borch;
    }
}


$masha = new Father(); 

echo 'У Маши - '.$masha->body.' тело<br>'; 
echo 'У Вани - '.$ivan->body.' тело<br>';

echo '<br>';
echo 'У Маши - '.$masha->body.' тело<br>'; 
echo 'У Вани - '.$ivan->body.' тело<br>';
echo '<br>';

echo 'У Машиного ';
$borch = $masha->getBorch();
echo $borch .' и улетный';
```

Comment: `private $borch` сделайте `protected $borch`, `parent::getBorch()` выполняется в контексе дочернего класса, которому запрещен доступ к private родительского

Comment: Благодарствую, но ничего не поменялось.